# In Javascript, what do you call this "identity function" - () => ({obj})

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I've seen this type of JavaScript code (contrived):

```
 const a = "hello"
 const b = () => ({a})
```

Is this just shorthand for this equivalent fat arrow function:

```
const b = () => { return {a} }
```

Or does it have some other purpose?  And what do you call these?

It seems a lot to add a construct just to save one reserved word.

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent. If an array function doesn't begin with `{`, it's just a shortcut that returns the expression.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific name for arrow functions that are just a single expression.

Comment: The extra `()` around the `{a}` are necessary to tell it that `{` does not start a block.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) calls the two forms of arrow functions *concise body* and *block body*.

Comment: Why do you call this an identity function? It does not return its input. Or anything related to its input.

Comment: It's not an identity function, it's a *constant* function (which always returns the same value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about the right side of an arrow function.

It is just more concise, with the special rule that if the right side is a single expression to be returned, it doesn't have to be `{ return expr }`, but just `expr`.

```
const sq = (x => x * x);
const hyphenAround = (s => `-${s}-`);
[1, 3, 5].map(a => a * a)
[1, 3, 5].reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

```js
const sq = (x => x * x);
const hyphenAround = (s => `-${s}-`);

console.log(sq(3));
console.log(hyphenAround("hello"));
console.log([1, 3, 5].map(a => a * a));
console.log([1, 3, 5].reduce((a, b) => a + b));
```

In your example, it is

```
const a = "hello"
const b = () => ({a})
```

which is the same as

```
const a = "hello"
const b = () => ({a: a})
```

Those are called [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

```js
let a = "hello"
const b = () => ({
  a
});

console.log(b());

a = "a long sentence";
console.log(b());

x = 123;
y = "hello"
z = [1, 3, 5];

console.log({
  x,
  y,
  z
});
```